# Xamarin: ADM - Could not start emulator using HOST GPU mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

showing a message:
Please check if you can update your video driver.
If it doesn't help, try to Edit the AVD and set "hw.gpu.mode=off".
[image]

Comment: the error message gives you two specific suggestions - have you tried them both?

Comment: @Jason yes i tried this

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the emulator before? And will this problem occur on other emulators? Please check the following doc to check the configurations first.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/

On my search, I found a simulator issue. It fixed through the way below.

Add the code below in `advancedFeatures.ini`.

```
WindowsHypervisorPlatform=on
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

You could find the file in the location:

```
C:\Users\userName\.android
```